# Search and replce a string in 10000 files

Tags: java, bash

EDIT: I have 10,000 identical files with below text in it.

```
TRANSACTION_ID=9093626660000000001,VAULT_REPORT_NAME=VUpldr_QA_1Mb_Report00001,DIMENSION=REGION:Europe;LOB:All LOB;CATEGORY:RO Reporting;CUSTOMER:All Customer;FREQUENCY:Daily;REPORT AUDIENCE:Apple RO Reporting;REPORT SUBSCRIPTION:Apple RO Reporting
```

My requirement is to replace as below in 10 k files.

1. TRANSACTION_ID from `9093626660000000001` to `9093626660000010000`. 
   and
2. VAULT_REPORT_NAME  from `VUpldr_QA_1Mb_Report00001` to
   `VUpldr_QA_1Mb_Report10000`

So my output files contents would be

> file 1st:

```
TRANSACTION_ID=9093626660000000001,VAULT_REPORT_NAME=VUpldr_QA_1Mb_Report00001,DIMENSION=REGION:Europe;LOB:All LOB;CATEGORY:RO Reporting;CUSTOMER:All Customer;FREQUENCY:Daily;REPORT AUDIENCE:Apple RO Reporting;REPORT SUBSCRIPTION:Apple RO Reporting
```

> file 2nd:

```
TRANSACTION_ID=9093626660000000002,VAULT_REPORT_NAME=VUpldr_QA_1Mb_Report00002,DIMENSION=REGION:Europe;LOB:All LOB;CATEGORY:RO Reporting;CUSTOMER:All Customer;FREQUENCY:Daily;REPORT AUDIENCE:Apple RO Reporting;REPORT SUBSCRIPTION:Apple RO Reporting
```

> file 10000th:

`TRANSACTION_ID=9093626660000010000,VAULT_REPORT_NAME=VUpldr_QA_1Mb_Report10000,DIMENSION=REGION:Europe;LOB:All LOB;CATEGORY:RO Reporting;CUSTOMER:All Customer;FREQUENCY:Daily;REPORT AUDIENCE:Apple RO Reporting;REPORT SUBSCRIPTION:Apple RO Reporting`

I wrote below code but that isn't working:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class mdScript {




    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        for (int i=1;i<=10000;i++){

        StringBuffer pathVarBuf = new StringBuffer();
        pathVarBuf.append("/Users/564169/Desktop/Vault_Testing/vUpldr/MD/1MbReport");
        pathVarBuf.append(i);
        pathVarBuf.append(".md");
        //System.out.println(pathVarBuf);
        Path path = Paths.get(pathVarBuf.toString());
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
        content = content.replaceAll("VUpldr_QA_1Mb_Report00001", "RVUpldr_QA_1Mb_Report"+i);
        int id=999900001; // (Transaction id in the org MD file is 90)
        id = id+i;
        content = content.replaceAll("999900001", Integer.toString(id));
        Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
        System.out.println(content);

        }

}

}
```

I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:267)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at mdScript.main(mdScript.java:22)
```

Comment: you can simply do it using any text editor's find in files and replace command e.g. notepad++

Comment: What I would do, is delete every file containing that text, and then writing that file with the new text if nothing is in there anyway.

Comment: If the files are **identical**, replace the text in one file, then delete the other 9999 files, and make 9999 copies of the first file.

Comment: yeah...that would have been easy, if there was 1 or 10 files....i have 10k files.replacing in each file will be tasky if done manually

Comment: i do not get..y have you given a negative to this question.Please help.i have a deadline to complete this today

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Do you really need to do it in Java? Do you need to do it only once? Simple bash script may be the perfect solution.

Comment: no not necessary..simple bash script will work for me:)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You can do it programmatically as well.

Simple solution will be using TextPad
Here is a link for the same
[TextPad find and replace in files](https://bruceatkinson.com/wp/some-examples-of-using-textpad-to-increase-productivity/)